# How to save an image to a variable using url react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to save image from a url in a variable and use it in the `Image` component in this example below I can load it directly, but I want to create a function to store it in a variable and use offline image

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 50,
  },
  tinyLogo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  logo: {
    width: 66,
    height: 58,
  },
});

const DisplayAnImage = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    
      <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        }}
      />
   
     
    </View>
  );
}

export default DisplayAnImage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to "save" the url in a variable.

Simply assign the url to a variable, for example:

> const imageUri = 'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.laramind.com%2Fblog%2Fpercorso-react-native-dal-livello-base-al-livello-avanzato%2F&psig=AOvVaw2Kb7DOrxfQ9hHdyuf-9m49&ust=1626099973147000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAoQjRxqFwoTCLDDv8yc2_ECFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD'

And use it in your image component:

> <Image src={{uri: imageUri}}/>

To use it offline you need to use an external library such as rn-fetch-blob, here an example app on how to do it:

```
// How to Download an Image in React Native from any URL
// https://aboutreact.com/download-image-in-react-native/

// Import React
import React from 'react';

// Import Required Components
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  Image,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';

// Import RNFetchBlob for the file download
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

const App = () => {
  const REMOTE_IMAGE_PATH =
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/gift.png'
  const checkPermission = async () => {
    
    // Function to check the platform
    // If iOS then start downloading
    // If Android then ask for permission

    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      downloadImage();
    } else {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
          {
            title: 'Storage Permission Required',
            message:
              'App needs access to your storage to download Photos',
          }
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          // Once user grant the permission start downloading
          console.log('Storage Permission Granted.');
          downloadImage();
        } else {
          // If permission denied then show alert
          alert('Storage Permission Not Granted');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        // To handle permission related exception
        console.warn(err);
      }
    }
  };

  const downloadImage = () => {
    // Main function to download the image
    
    // To add the time suffix in filename
    let date = new Date();
    // Image URL which we want to download
    let image_URL = REMOTE_IMAGE_PATH;    
    // Getting the extention of the file
    let ext = getExtention(image_URL);
    ext = '.' + ext[0];
    // Get config and fs from RNFetchBlob
    // config: To pass the downloading related options
    // fs: Directory path where we want our image to download
    const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
    let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir;
    let options = {
      fileCache: true,
      addAndroidDownloads: {
        // Related to the Android only
        useDownloadManager: true,
        notification: true,
        path:
          PictureDir +
          '/image_' + 
          Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2) +
          ext,
        description: 'Image',
      },
    };
    config(options)
      .fetch('GET', image_URL)
      .then(res => {
        // Showing alert after successful downloading
        console.log('res -> ', JSON.stringify(res));
        // res.base64() 
        // res.path()
        alert('Image Downloaded Successfully.');
      });
  };

  const getExtention = filename => {
    // To get the file extension
    return /[.]/.exec(filename) ?
             /[^.]+$/.exec(filename) : undefined;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30, textAlign: 'center' }}>
          React Native Image Download Example
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 25,
            marginTop: 20,
            marginBottom: 30,
            textAlign: 'center',
          }}>
          www.aboutreact.com
        </Text>
      </View>
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: REMOTE_IMAGE_PATH,
        }}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: 100,
          resizeMode: 'contain',
          margin: 5
        }}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={checkPermission}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          Download Image
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  button: {
    width: '80%',
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    margin: 10,
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: yes, i just want to use this image offline

Comment: cool, how can I get this image that you downloaded and load it into the Image component, or is there a way to convert this Image into Base64 string and use it in the component?

Comment: No need to convert it into Base64. In the res you will have the local path of the image that you can use as a uri in the Image component.
Please accept the answer if I solved the issue

Comment: I didn't understand, could you show an example?

Comment: I added two example in the fetch function. Both ways (res.base64(), res.path()) can be used in the Image src prop to show it). Please accept the answer if I solved the issue